# What is the character etymology of 風?

Tags: kanji, etymology

The Etymological Dictionary of Han Chinese Characters (which is the pdf/book format of the database for an old website called "Kanji Networks") states:

> 風 (9) フウ;フ;かざ;かぜ
>   A variant form of 鳳 (large bird flapping its wings), later conceived of as the source of *wind* causing various life forms and other objects to flutter → *trend*; *atmosphere*; *taste*; *custom* (← things brought in then carried off by the wind).

Wiktionary states:

> Phono-semantic compound (形聲, OC *plum, *plums): phonetic 凡 (OC *bom) + semantic 虫 (“insects”). Ancient Chinese thought insects appear with wind. (Insects refer to any kind of animal, such as tigers (大蟲)).

Most other dictionaries I've searched online seem to agree with the latter (at least somewhat), but which is correct? I find it harder to believe that something so common as the wind would be a derived from a mythological bird, although its a much cooler explanation than the wind causing animals to appear.

Has anyone ever seen the former etymology before? Does this mean Kanji Networks and their dictionary is not to be trusted at all? I'm a relatively new learner of Japanese and so I'm not sure if its a known discredited source. Or am I missing something here? Any help appreciated. Apologies if this isn't the right place for this question, please move it somewhere its more likely to be answered if so.
Thanks!

Comment: Non-academic resources sometimes are very accurate, but most of the time they range from anything to *half-accurate whilst over-interpreting some aspects* to *completely inaccurate*, for the sake of making mnemonics. There's nothing wrong with using mnemonics based on non-factual information, though, and real academic information is extremely hard to come by. In this instance, Kanji Networks is more accurate than Wiktionary, although it is still a bit off with the over-interpretation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「風」(*wind*) and「鳳」([*Chinese male mythical bird*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenghuang)) share the same origins. The origin of「風」is nothing more than a differentiation from「鳳」; previously, since「風」did not have its own character, it just used「鳳」as a phonetic loan (note that they both have the two *On'yomi* **ふう** and **ほう**).

---

「鳳」was originally a picture of an elaborately adorned mythical bird with a large crown and long tail feathers.

## <kbd>A
[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.39.10
[合集13339](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=13339&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Later on, a sound hint「凡」was added, and the bird tails became even more elaborately adorned.

## <kbd>B
商
甲
[image]
[後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.30.6
[合集38186](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=38186&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>商
甲
[image]
[燕](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)147「凡」
[合集18875](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=18875&jgwfl=)</kbd>

The adornments on the bird tails eventually separated from the bird itself.

## <kbd>C
[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
中方鼎
[集成2752](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2752&jgwfl=)</kbd>

During this period of change, some inscriptions may have used a simpler, less elaborate bird shape that eventually evolved to「隹/鳥」(these two are variants).「凡」also grew to cover the entire bird. These changes lead on to the modern「鳳」.

## <kbd>B
商
甲
[image]
後2.30.6
合集38186</kbd><kbd>D
商ㆍ[殷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinxu)
甲
[image]
[拾](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)7.9
[合集30234](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30234&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>E

[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>F
現代
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

Another variant saw most of the structure of the bird being omitted. Take one of the separated tail adornments from form **C**, and remove the top circle-dot shape「⊙」. We're left with「凡」and a very simple remnant of the adornment, leading on to the modern「風」.

## <kbd>C
西周
金
[image]
中方鼎
集成2752</kbd><kbd>G
[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
[image]
[帛甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)1.31</kbd>
　<kbd>H
[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)ㆍ[秦2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)</kbd>
　<kbd>I
現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

> There is no particular reason to remove「⊙」, which is why we have variants which kept「⊙」and removed the other part.「風」became the more popular variant due to an accident in history.
>
> ## <kbd>J
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文古文</kbd>
> 　<kbd>K
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]
> 「凬」</kbd>

「虫」has nothing to do with「風」!「虫」originally depicted a poisonous snake (now written「虺」; the meaning *insects* was strictly written as「蟲」in [Kyūjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai) before becoming simplified to「虫」).「風」and「虫」converged in shape because the reduced adornment looked very graphically similar to the snake since very early on.

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8718
[合集22296](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=22296&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>西周
金
[image]
虫⿱爫日作旅鼎
[集成2175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2175&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>秦
簡
[image]
睡ㆍ[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)62背</kbd>
　
<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 李學勤《字源》
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 裘錫圭《文字學概要》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Comment: Wow that's quite an HTML artwork!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer @droooze! It seems that several places mention "wind brings insects". I found this in a book called "Body, Subject and Power in China":
"The Han Dynasty dictionary Shuowen suggests that the insect radical in the character for wind derives from the fact that insects stir when the wind blows."
If the ancient Chinese (at least as far as the Shuowen) really did think that wind brings insects/animals, would that not be an explanation for how the plume of the phoenix's tail was simplified to a (albeit modified) insect/snake? Or did this belief arise from the character?

Comment: @KingOfDust Shuowen is a very traditional source of explanations. The author, Xu Shen, did a good job with what he had, but note that (1) he was not a linguist and had pre-scientific thinking, and (2) by the time Shuowen was written, more than 1,000 years have already passed from the earliest inscriptions we've dug up already. We have more resources now than Xu Shen ever had to gather information. If there is an association between Wind and Insects, it wasn't there originally and arose from erroneous thinking - but it is entirely possible for originally erroneous thinking to become tradition.

Comment: @KingOfDust many publications today deal with erroneous information in Shuowen, such as one of the references I mentioned - 季旭昇《說文新證》.

Comment: Now I'm curious if the elaborate bird initially referenced by this character might have been a peacock -- similar bobble-feathers on the head like a crown, and similar long and elaborate tail feathers.  Also, not native to China, but endemic to India, close enough that descriptions of the bird might have been known in China.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi that is something I don't have the knowledge to go into haha..Some people think that it was originally an elevation of the Rooster to mythical status (probably due to the crown as well; also the zodiac connection mentioned in the Fenghuang wiki page). Anyway, 鳳 had precursors in several [Chinese neolithic cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Neolithic_cultures_of_China), I think the answer lies there.

Comment: Looks like the green peacock's native range historically included southern China: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_peafowl

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I'm actually fond of that idea, as well as 龍 being crocodile and 貘 being panda :P

Comment: what's the source of those pretty images @droooze? (great answers btw)

Comment: Thanks @boiko! The majority of images I use come from [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/), which is amazing for anything apart from Clerical, Running, and Cursive script. Occasionally I will Photoshop something from one of the references I quote, if 小學堂 doesn't have something I'm looking for.

Comment: cool, thanks for the reference! I find http://hanziyuan.net useful to mine for images (not so much for the theories).

Comment: @boiko ah yes, Sears' collection of OBI images is impressive. His revamped site seems more reliable now. There were a lot of mistakes in the site before - the one I remember was the site putting OB samples of 育 under the page for 居, which is an interpretation mistake on his behalf. The site still crucially misses [bamboo and slip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) and [Chu silk manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript) sections though, and these provide an extremely important link between Western Zhou characters to Qin-Han characters...

Comment: again, thanks, that's all very interesting. incidentally, have you seen Ochiai Atsushi's approach ([one](http://amzn.asia/d/1cRLhFp), [two](http://amzn.asia/d/dbI4Aoi)) and if so, what's your opinion of it? (sorry, I've been dying to ask this to someone who's into this stuff…)

Comment: @boiko Unfortunately I don't have access to those books. I had a look at the foreword to 漢字の成り立ち from what Amazon preview would allow, and the author correctly identified that the development of character analysis has greatly progressed in the past 30 years, but there was no mention *why* it has progressed so much (this mostly has to do with a more integrated approach with linguistics e.g. by Zhengzhang and Baxter-Sagart, + discovery of more Warring States archaeological samples), and I'm rather concerned about the lack of mention of many of the premier scholars in the field.

Comment: I'd like to look at one of the last chapters though (最新の成果), a comparison of this analysis with some of the other titles I usually reference would be really interesting. I can't comment on 甲骨文字小字典, there's no preview for that title.